# Spring: User Login not reading from database

Tags: database, spring, security, spring-mvc, jdbc

I'm trying to set up a Spring Security Login akin to this question (the problem seems identical to mine and I did attempt the solution but no go)

Using MySQL Workbench, my SQL is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mtc`.`authorities` (
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `authority` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mtc`.`users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mtc`.`users` (
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `member_type` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `grade` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ad_line1` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ad_line2` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ad_city` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ad_county` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_num` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `em_con_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `em_con_num` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

All my database stuff is working fine, in that I can connect via jdbc, I can display information, I can write to the database. Security is also working, in that I can enable and block access to pages. I can also login with hard coded values in the XML (if I remove these, I still get the same issue)

security-context.xml

```
<security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="chris" authorities="admin"
                    password="chris" />
                <security:user name="sorin" authorities="admin"
                    password="sorin" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="select username,password, enabled from users where username = ?" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>


    <security:http use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/static/**" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/members" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/createmembers" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/register" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/registerSuccess" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/login"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />
    </security:http>
```

My login page is just giving me the error=true tag upon redirect to the login page so it seems to be set up correctly.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: For starters your users table has no column named *enabled*.

Comment: Apologies. I imported the wrong MySQL model, as I'm working between two machines. That seems to have fixed it though, but I'm 100% sure I have the enabled on the other machine and it wasn't working. I'll just copy this model for that machine.

Comment: You can find the problem easier if you log the ouput of org.springframework.security at DEBUG level.

Comment: I'll look into that tomorrow. I think the issue may have been that I had enabled defaulting to 0 on the other database. Will have to check in the morning.

Comment: It's just stopped working again, when I was looking at method security and changed roles from admin to ROLE_ADMIN and member to ROLE_MEMBER. Can't see any reason. Can you advise how to do what you've suggested? I've never really done any debugging with Eclipse so what you're suggesting is very foreign to me!

Comment: Logging is the one thing you absolutely need when you're developing.  It's a crucial part (with a debugger) in finding problems that may  be occurring. This could help you get on configuring http://www.mograblog.com/2013/03/slf4j-with-logback-in-maven-project.html